# Flutter imagepicker chose image methods

Tags: flutter, dialog, modal-dialog, imagepicker

I was wondering what the best practice, maybe most professional method to let the user select a picture from the gallery and afterwards type a displayname for the picture. What I can see and after asking chatGPT, it seems to be either use a modal-window or a dialog-window for this behaviour. What do you guys think? is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a popup dialog with a text field is the most elegant way to ask a user for input.

How do you let the user select an image? Via a button?
You could implement the logic that every time the image is selected, a dialog pops up with a text box asking the user for the display name.